# Can I add spacing around an icon in Flutter Bottom Navigation Bar?

Tags: flutter, font-awesome

I have a Bottom Navigation Bar in Flutter, and plan on using Font Awesome Icons for the items. However, when compared to material icons, font awesome icons don't have any spacing around them. This makes them touch the Bottom Navigation Bar Item titles. Is there any way i can add space between these?

Bottom Navigation Bar Code:

```
BottomNavigationBar(
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
                currentIndex: _currentIndex,
                items: [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.list,
                      size: 30.0,
                    ),
                    title: Text('Notice Board'),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.handsHelping,

                      // size: 30.0,
                    ),
                    title: Text('Services'),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.add,
                      size: 35.0,

                    ),
                    title: Text('Create'),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
                  ),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.store,
                      // size: 30.0,
                    ),
                    title: Text('Marketplace'),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
                  ),
                ],
                onTap: (index) {
                  setState(() {
                    _currentIndex = index;
                  });
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to add a Padding widget (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html) around your Icon that uses Font awesome.

Comment: Thank you! I just discovered that the bottom navbar icon parameter has the type Widget, so any item including Container, Text, or (like you said) Padding, does the trick.

Answer (score 15):

My usage of @Ludovic Garon answer

`icon: Padding(
   padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
   child: Icon(Icons.search),
),`

Answer (score 3):

Use `IconButton` instead of `Icon`
like this:

```
 IconButton(
          icon: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
            onPressed: (){},
          ),
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this, if your Icon is designed to have labels fixed, specify  the height property for the in textStyle

```
...selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(height: 1.5,fontSize: 12),
        unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize:12, height: 1.5),
```